# Qt QComboBox popup position

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I'm working on an application which contains an editable `QComboBox`. I observe the following behavior when I enter some text in the edit field and press the dropdown arrow in the combobox:

[image]

My edit line ends up hidden behind the item `"e@abc.com"`. I would like to have the combobox list popup *below* the edit field, like in the below screen:

[image]

The first screen above is taken on Ubuntu with Qt 4.5 while the second screen is from Suse 11 with Qt 4.4. I'm not aware of any differences regarding change of behavior of `QComboBox` popups between Qt 4.4 and Qt 4.5. Regardless, I would like the list to behave the same in both distributions.

This is a standard `QComboBox` with the editable property set to on - there are no stylesheets or special formatting applied to it.

How can I make the list popup below the editable field, like in the second screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a style issue, as the screenshots are taken with different styles. Perhaps you can start investigating by changing style on the failing desktop.

Comment: It was indeed the style (not the theme). Turns out this is configured with qtconfig (I didn't even have this package installed on Ubuntu). 

I now set my Qt app to use cleanlooks style using setStyle("cleanlooks") so it will look the same on all distributions.